# Как сохранить картинки метафайл в папку

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Для отрисовки картинок на форме, я использовала этот код [Как извлечь метафайл из TOleContainer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861008/how-to-extract-metafile-from-tolecontainer/4206425#4206425)

Теперь мне нужно их как-нибудь сохранить в папку. Вот эта строка сохраняет только пустую картинку, без самой картинки. Как мне это исправить?

```
bmp.SaveToFile(Path+'Img'+IntToStr(I+1)+'.bmp');
```

Код:

```
for I := 0 to 4 do begin 
    ViewObject2.GetExtent(DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, Nil, ViewSize);
    DC := GetDC(0);
    AdjustedSize.X := MulDiv(ViewSize.X, GetDeviceCaps(DC, LOGPIXELSX), 2540);
    AdjustedSize.Y := MulDiv(ViewSize.Y, GetDeviceCaps(DC, LOGPIXELSY), 2540);
    bmp:=TBitmap.Create;
    Bmp.Height := AdjustedSize.Y;
    Bmp.Width := AdjustedSize.X;
    SetRect(Rc, 0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height);
    bmp.SaveToFile(Path+'Img'+IntToStr(I+1)+'.bmp');
    OleDraw(ReObject.poleobj, DVASPECT_CONTENT, Canvas.Handle, Rc);
end;
```

Comment: А где вы эти картинки берете? Использовать OLE контайнер для отрисовки картинок - это хм... несколько неожиданно.

Comment: Картинки беру из компонента RichEdit

Comment: Код свой покажете?

Comment: Вот исходник https://yadi.sk/d/AMI3pGmdqcs2ag. Для работы программы нужно создать папку C:\temp\richedit

Comment: Создавать `TBitmap` и проводить аллокацию `HDC` в "теле" цикла не совсем корректно. Кроме того, в приведенном Вами коде не наблюдается высвобождения данных ресурсов.

Comment: По другому всё равно не знаю как сделать, так что не важно.

Answer (score 0):

Может сначала 
`OleDraw(ReObject.poleobj, DVASPECT_CONTENT, Canvas.Handle, Rc);`
а потом `save`?
У Вас в коде наоборот. BMP создан, задан размер, сохранен, а потом на нем идёт отрисовка.

Comment: Всё правильно работает только у меня ошибка в коде, надо вот так

Comment: OleDraw(ReObject.poleobj, DVASPECT_CONTENT, Bmp.Canvas.Handle, Rc);

Comment: Сейчас пытаюсь все картинки добавить в новый компонент RichEdit просто в цикл написала процедуру InsertBitmapToRE(RichEdit2.Handle, Bmp.Handle); и они почему то при нажатии кнопки "скопировать файлы", добавляются задом наперёд в чём может быть проблема? http://vfl.ru/fotos/2dec0d6d23333199.html